# Selecting specific rows from a table, using a group by query

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+
| Date       | Name       | Certificates |
+------------+------------+--------------+
| 2021-02-01 | Jason      | 3            |
| 2021-02-01 | Nisha      | 4            |
| 2021-02-01 | Zaid       | 5            |
| 2021-03-25 | Aniket     | 4            |
| 2021-03-25 | Anish      | 2            |
| 2021-03-25 | Nadia      | 0            |
| 2021-05-06 | Aadil      | 7            |
| 2021-05-06 | Ashish     | 1            |
| 2021-05-06 | Rahil      | 9            |
+------------+------------+--------------+
```

This result is obtained by performing the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
    Date, Name, COUNT(Certificates) as Certificates
FROM Students.data
GROUP BY Date, Name
ORDER BY Date, Name;
```

After receiving this result, ideally, I would like only the first entry from each date now (that would basically be the first name for each date), which should be something like this:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+
| Date       | Name       | Certificates |
+------------+------------+--------------+
| 2021-02-01 | Jason      | 3            |
| 2021-03-25 | Aniket     | 4            |
| 2021-05-06 | Aadil      | 7            |
+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Is there a way I can modify the above group by query to obtain the result, or do I need to pass the result of this query to some other query, if so, what would that query be.
Thanks.

Also, the database I am using is Clickhouse.

NOTE: Please let me know if there is any issue with the question, can clarify that.

Comment: You need to define what "first" record from each date actually means here.  It is not clear from your question.

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen I have made the edits, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar do you expect 3,4,7 in the final output or 1 for all of them in the certificate column

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar check the result below https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5a8bf3f6934f18b19d331d3ba43570a is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- straightforward way

```sql
SELECT Date, untuple(groupArray(tuple(Name, Certificates))[1])
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM  (
        /* Emulate the test dataset. */
        SELECT toDate(data.1) AS Date, data.2 AS Name, data.3 AS Certificates
        FROM (
            SELECT arrayJoin([
                ('2021-02-01', 'Jason ', 3),
                ('2021-02-01', 'Nisha ', 4),
                ('2021-02-01', 'Zaid  ', 5),
                ('2021-03-25', 'Aniket', 4),
                ('2021-03-25', 'Anish ', 2),
                ('2021-03-25', 'Nadia ', 0),
                ('2021-05-06', 'Aadil ', 7),
                ('2021-05-06', 'Ashish', 1),
                ('2021-05-06', 'Rahil ', 9)]) AS data
            )
        )
    ORDER BY Date, Name
    )
GROUP BY Date

/*
┌───────Date─┬─Name───┬─Certificates─┐
│ 2021-02-01 │ Jason  │            3 │
│ 2021-03-25 │ Aniket │            4 │
│ 2021-05-06 │ Aadil  │            7 │
└────────────┴────────┴──────────────┘
*/
```

- way based on window-function

Starting from [version 21.4](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/) added the *full* support of window-functions. At this moment it was marked as an *experimental feature*.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    Date,
    FIRST_VALUE(Name) OVER w AS FirstName,
    FIRST_VALUE(Certificates) OVER w AS FirstCertificates
FROM 
(
    /* Emulate the test dataset. */
    SELECT toDate(data.1) AS Date, data.2 AS Name, data.3 AS Certificates
    FROM (
        SELECT arrayJoin([
            ('2021-02-01', 'Jason ', 3),
            ('2021-02-01', 'Nisha ', 4),
            ('2021-02-01', 'Zaid  ', 5),
            ('2021-03-25', 'Aniket', 4),
            ('2021-03-25', 'Anish ', 2),
            ('2021-03-25', 'Nadia ', 0),
            ('2021-05-06', 'Aadil ', 7),
            ('2021-05-06', 'Ashish', 1),
            ('2021-05-06', 'Rahil ', 9)]) AS data
        )
)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Name ASC)
SETTINGS allow_experimental_window_functions = 1

/*
┌───────Date─┬─FirstName─┬─FirstCertificates─┐
│ 2021-02-01 │ Jason     │                 3 │
│ 2021-03-25 │ Aniket    │                 4 │
│ 2021-05-06 │ Aadil     │                 7 │
└────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┘
*/
```

See https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-window-functions-current-state-of-the-art.

Answer (score 2):

You consider your result an intermediate result of which you want to pick one row per date. You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this to number the rows per date by name and only keep a date's first row (those rows numbered 1).

```
SELECT date, name, certificates
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    date, name, COUNT(Certificates) AS certificates,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY name) AS rn
  FROM students.data
  GROUP BY date, name
) numbered
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY date;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93c3682bda72cb4fe53fbbe8053a8acb (using MySQL 8 here, because dbfiddle.uk doesn't feature clickhouse, but the query is standard SQL compliant, so we can use about every modern RDBMS for the demonstration).

Comment: The question was worded terribly...leaving me to think that maybe the interpretation of the OP's approach was also overthought.  This looks correct +1.

Comment: doing count() is not necessary if you are filtering by rank = 1

Comment: @trillion: You are wrong. Look at the request again. The table shown there is the result of aggregating the data table by date and name and counting their rows. Without `COUNT` we don't get the number of certificates.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner your code returns 1 only for ceritificate column, is that expected ? because the output that he showed above has 3,4,7 in the certificate column

Comment: @ThorstenKettner here is the fiddle for your query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=186354fcb853631b7bd1991987972ee7, I believe what he needs is this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5a8bf3f6934f18b19d331d3ba43570a

Comment: @ThorstenKettner any comments ?

Comment: @trillion: This is because you are counting counts. You are treating the OP's query result as the original table and then invoke their query again on that data. This is wrong. The original table has multiple rows per student and date (of which some or all have a certificate). The query then counts the certificates per date and name. Only then do we get the counts 3, 4, 5, 4, etc., and of these we want to keep one row per date.

Comment: i think it's not clear what the user wants then since your query only returns 1 and the expected output by the person is 3,47

Comment: @trillion: No. *Please* read the request. The OP shows a table. You know what a table is? A table can be a stored table or a result of a query. The OP tells us the table they are showing is a query result ("This result is obtained by performing the following SQL query"), but you use this query result and apply about the same query again. If you want to make a fiddle, then create some table data for which OP's query results in the table they are showing.

Comment: Well, I added a demo fiddle to my answer so as to dispel any doubts :-)

Answer (score 0):

While looking at your output, I assumed that you wanted the sole entry for the day to be the one with alphabetically ASC on Name column.

In such case, you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function if this SQL server

```
SELECT Date,Name, Certificates
FROM
(
SELECT 
    Date, Name, 
    Certificates=COUNT(Certificates) OVER (PARTITION BY Date,Name) 
    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date
     ORDER BY Name ASC) 
FROM Students.data
) T 
WHERE RowNumber =1 
ORDER BY Date ASC
;
```

Comment: All modern DBMS support window functions like `row_number()` not only SQL Server (which was actually quite late to that party)

Comment: @trillion edited. Thank you for spotting that

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya thank you . edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

- use `CTE` instead of Subquery
- rank the data => each row will have same data with an increasing rank --> `ROW_NUMBER`
- filter the rank_ by by 1 to get one entry per date
- the order by is on name in alphabetical order assuming that what you need

If you don't have the count already then use **code 1**
fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5a8bf3f6934f18b19d331d3ba43570a

WITH ranked_data AS (
SELECT date_, name,
count(certificates_) over(partition by date_,name) as certificates,
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY date_ order by name) as rank_
FROM students
)
SELECT
date_, name, certificates FROM ranked_data WHERE rank_ = 1

if you have the count then use **code 2**

```
WITH ranked_data AS (
SELECT date_, name, certificates_,
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY date_ order by name) as rank_
FROM students
)
SELECT 
  date_, name, certificates_ FROM ranked_data WHERE rank_ = 1
```